# Arduino sending SmS using sim800l

Tags: string, arduino, gsm

how can i write the phone number to the arduino using Sim800l module...
the right code is this 
    `serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+639261001204\"\r\n");`
i want to to change the phone number to String so that i can send any      number...

```
void send()
 {
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
     serialSIM800.begin(9600);
     delay(1000);
     char s1 = "AT+CMGS=\"+";
     char s2= number;
     char s3="\"\r\n"";
     char sms = s1+s2+s3;
     //Set SMS format to ASCII
     serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
     delay(1000);
     //Send new SMS command and message number
     serialSIM800.write(sms);
     delay(1000);
     //Send SMS content
     serialSIM800.write("Your student Go inside the School");
     delay(1000);
     serialSIM800.write((char)26);
     delay(250);
 }
```